# Align text to the right in google forms

Tags: google-forms

How I can align a text to the right in google forms to fit Arabic language?I changed language settings at google account to Arabic to align it to the right, but the text align to left again when i sent the link to another user. My link https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1VRl63dgiOMFKtiOPAhzWY0SLHSJz6g1B6Z2ZKyri-Q8/edit

I can't ask all respondents to change there settings. However I found a form at the web works well without changing the setting of my account/device. See the link

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfsjmkeaSMnQVik2HL0gd-omqJZI6eITh3KAKkphf5BXLghUg/viewform#start=publishanalytics

So there is a solution but I don't know the author of this form to ask him. Could you please help?

Regards,

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you been able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately changing your language settings only changes your form to right justified. others filling your form will see it left justified if their google language settings in english

Answer (score -2):

It is easy, **turn your Google Drive language to Arabic**, and everything will appear **Right-to-Left**, including your forms (Settings - Language - Arabic)

Comment: It only changes what you see by yourself.